# Mapping DTO to Entity with ModelMapper including exceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am having a DTO (OpeningHoursPeriodDTO) and an Entity (OpeningHoursPeriod), which I want to map using ModelMapper.
As long I throw no exception inside the converter method all is working fine as expected.

Here the code of the converter:

```
modelMapper
        .createTypeMap(OpeningHoursPeriodDTO.class, OpeningHoursPeriod.class)
        .setConverter(converter -> {
            OpeningHoursPeriodDTO openingHoursPeriodDTO = converter.getSource();
            if (openingHoursPeriodDTO == null) {
                return null;
            }

            if (openingHoursPeriodDTO.getOpen() == null || openingHoursPeriodDTO.getClose() == null) {
                throw new BadRequestException("Opening hours and closing hours must be present");
            }

            if (!Objects.equals(
                    openingHoursPeriodDTO.getOpen().getDay(),
                    openingHoursPeriodDTO.getClose().getDay())) {
                throw new BadRequestException("Opening and close day for a period must be for the same day");
            }

            return OpeningHoursPeriod.builder()
                    .id(openingHoursPeriodDTO.getId())
                    .day(openingHoursPeriodDTO.getOpen().getDay())
                    .openTime(LocalTime.parse(openingHoursPeriodDTO.getOpen().getTime(), TIME_FORMATTER))
                    .closeTime(LocalTime.parse(openingHoursPeriodDTO.getClose().getTime(), TIME_FORMATTER))
                    .build();
        });
```

The problem is that if it happens to throw an Exception, I get a 500 Status Code in my Spring Boot application, although the status code of the `BadRequestException` should be 400.
Any Idea how to best handle such converter exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

You could add @ResponseStatus to your exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

This will generate a 400 when this exception is thrown.

But there are various other options to handle exceptions in REST Controllers. Have a look here:

https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: that is exactly what I have on my BadRequestException, but somehow ModelMapper eats it and then throws an 500

Comment: Maybe the exception is wrapped. Do you see a stack trace?

Comment: yeah. my exception is getting wrapped through a `org.modelmapper.MappingException`

Comment: Then you should use a ControllerAdvice and handle MappingException and then check for the cause and return 400 when it's a BadRequestException: 4. New Solution 3 – The New @ControllerAdvice (Spring 3.2 And Above)